# How to assign permissions to a single publishing page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, security, document, item

As I know that a publishing page is a securable object, and in my case I need to grant certain users the permissions to Read certain pages in my publishing site (they cannot read other pages), in addition to the users that are inherited from parent site . To do so I did the following:-

1. I edit the page I need to grant the permission to

[image]

2. I stop inheriting the permission.
3. But I cannot find a button to create new group to specify the users that can see this document only?

[image]

Second point I am wondering about , why I have to stop the permissions inheritance to be able to modify the permissions>.  In my case I  still want to have the same security setting inherited from the parent site (and any updates made to it) , but I need also to add certain users to be able to read certain pages within this site in addition to the inherited users from parent site..
Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New groups are created in Site Settings and can then be applied to the page.

Permissions inheritance is just that, it inherits from a parent. For a page, that parent is either a folder or the document library itself. Breaking the permissions inheritance means you need custom permissions on something that is different from the parent and therefore will have unique permissions.

If permissions are granted via Sharepoint groups, changes to group memberships will be reflected on the item, but specific permission changes will not be. So user is added to the group, they can then see the page, but if the group at the parent level goes from Read to Contribute permissions, your page will still have the group at Read permission.

So in your case, the page will have the permissions granted when the inheritance is broken and will allow you to then add a user group to the list who might not have direct access to the site.